# UK Tier-2 visa holder

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, isle-of-man

I am an Indian national and hold a Tier-2 work visa and a BRP card.  Can I travel, without requiring a visa, to the Isle of Man?

Answer (score 4):

According to this page, the answer is yes:

https://www.gov.im/categories/travel-traffic-and-motoring/immigration/

> If you have a valid visa issued by the Home Office, United Kingdom Border Agency (UKBA), Bailiwick of Jersey or Bailiwick of Guernsey then you will be able to visit the Isle of Man.

However:

> While visiting the Isle of Man you will not be able to work or study and there is no recourse to public finds.

Comment: Nice. Plus 'visit' in that context means 3 days.

Comment: @GayotFow do you mean that the UK visa would not be valid for a 4-day trip?

Comment: Yes, right. If caught the person can be detained.

Comment: @GayotFow that seems like a fairly serious omission on that gov.im page.

Comment: It's in the operations manual. It's online, but I don't have a link (I use the hard copy). They only release parts of it in response to FOI requests but you should be able to dig down and check it out. Look in Volume 2 IIRC. Are you seriously trying to confirm this point? If so let me know and I'll dig out the stuff from my hard copy.

Comment: In response to FOI's they release a page at at time on the net.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm not seriously trying to confirm the point, I'm just shocked that the Isle of Man can have a web page saying "you can visit if you have a UK visa" without mentioning that you could be detained if you stay for four days or longer.